# Why can I not convert a reverse iterator to a forward iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

Well, I know why, it's because there isn't a conversion, but why isn't there a conversion? Why can forward iterators be turned to reverse iterators but not the other way round? And more importantly, what can I do if I want to do this? Is there some adapter that allows you to iterate backwards using a forward iterator?

```
std::vector<int> buffer(10);
std::vector<int>::iterator forward = buffer.begin();
std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator backward = buffer.rbegin();
++forward;
++backward;
std::vector<int>::iterator forwardFromBackward = std::vector<int>::iterator(backward); // error! Can't convert from reverse_iterator to iterator!
std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator backwardFromForward = std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator(forward); // this is fine
```

Comment: There is a conversion: `backward.base();`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use `reverse_iterator` where needed by passing iterator type as template argument wherever you use `iterator`. Doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: You're absolutely right ybungalobill; my actual code is a bit more complex than this and I tried base() but it gave me errors so I gave up on it and my brain erased my knowledge of it. Thanks! If you add that exact text as an answer, I'll accept it, since really it *is* an answer.

Comment: @Ben: Then probably you should understand what errors you got when you used 'base()'. I'm still curious why isn't there a default conversion.

Comment: @Grozz, but the reverse_iterator contains the regular iterator as a member and you can extract it with base().

Comment: @ybungalobill You mean why it doesn't implicitly convert? Because implicit conversions are evil. With iterator->const_iterator it isn't really an implicit conversion, it is an implicit constructor which isn't quite as evil. An implicit constructor to iterator from reverse_iterator might have been possible.

Comment: @ybungalobill, Turns out I couldn't understand the errors because it was a compiler bug in VC10, to do with auto, declarator lists and functions similar to base() (returning a templated type different to the templated class it's called on). I reported it and it's apparently fixed for VC11.

Comment: @ybungalobill That's not a conversion, it's the physical iterator. It is actually `(backward+1).base()`. Reason: for `reverse_iterator`, the physical location of a `reverse_iterator` is [_the element before_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14760316/111307).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could write a helper function. One particularity of `reverse_iterator` is that `base()` gives a forward iterator that is next from the value that the reverse iterator dereferences to. [This is because a reverse iterator **physically points to the element *after* the one it *logically* points to**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14760316/111307).  So to have the forward iterator to the same item as your reverse_iterator, you'll need to decrement the result of `base()` by one, *or* you could increment the reverse iterator *first*, then take the `.base()` of that.

Both examples are shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

//result is undefined if passed container.rend()
template <class ReverseIterator>
typename ReverseIterator::iterator_type make_forward(ReverseIterator rit)
{
    return --(rit.base()); // move result of .base() back by one.
    // alternatively
    // return (++rit).base() ;
    // or
    // return (rit+1).base().
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(1, 1);
    std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator rit = vec.rbegin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator fit = make_forward(rit);
    std::cout << *fit << ' ' << *rit << '\n';
}
```

Warning: this behavior is different from that of the `reverse_iterator(iterator)` constructor.

Comment: Looks like ybungalobill doesn't want the rep, so as the first answer to mention base() you win :) Thanks!

Comment: @Abyx: Yes, since you cannot decrement the temporary pointer returned from `rit.base()`, it might be better to create a named variable of `iterator_type` first. No specialization should be needed, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's very common to have two (reverse) iterators span a range of values (such as in `begin(),end()` and `rbegin(),rend()`). For any range described by the two reverse iterators `rA,rB`, the range `rB.base(),rA.base()` will span the same range in the forward direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec{10,11,12,13,14,15};

  // spans the range from 13 to 10
  auto rfirst=std::rbegin(vec)+2;
  auto rlast=std::rend(vec);

  // Loops forward, prints 10 11 12 13
  for(auto it = rlast.base(); it != rfirst.base(); ++it){
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  }
}
```

If conceptually you are only interested in a single item (such as the result of `find_if`), then use `make_forward` by @visitor. Even in this case, the range idea helps to keep track of the validity of the reverse iterator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec{10,11,12,13,14,15};

  auto rfirst=std::rbegin(vec);
  auto rlast=std::rend(vec);

  auto rfound = std::find_if(rfirst,rlast, [](int v){ return v<13; });

  if(rfound != rlast){
    std::cout << *rfound << " "; // prints 12
    auto forwardFound = make_forward(rfound) ; 
    std::cout << *forwardFound << " "; // prints 12
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get forward iterator from reverse iterator using this code

```
container.begin() + (reverseIter - container.rbegin() - 1);
```

Comment: _Why_.  Over a large list you are asking for lots of excessive traversal, and this is much messier than simply `(reverseIter+1).base()`

Comment: What list? it's a *vector*.

Comment: If you're using iterators (as opposed to simple integer indexing), I assume the reason you're doing this is to be able to apply this formula to any `std::container` that uses iterators.  `std::list` traversal is more expensive than `std::vector`, so you're much better off with traversing (just 1 element).

Comment: @bobobobo, meh and what if you're using a container which doesn't use `std::reverse_iterator`?

Comment: Then the question is moot?