# Why does removing the _first_ element of a list invalidate `.rend()`?

Tags: c++, stdlist, reverse-iterator

Tested on Mac OS X using XCode 4.6.

This example code shows removing the last element of an `std::list` works as I expected:  an iterator reference to `list::end()` is still "1 past the end" and is still valid, ***even through removal of the last element***.

But the second example counters my intuition.  Removing the *first* element of the list **changes `list::rend()`**, which I thought was "1 past the beginning".

Was my expectation wrong?  Why was it wrong?  Why does your reference to "1 past the end" through deletion of the last element remain valid (should it not?), but a reference to "1 in front of the beginning (`.rend()`) becomes invalid after removal of the front element?

```
void printList( list<int>& os )
{
  for( int& i : os )
    printf( "%d ", i ) ;
  puts("");
}

void testList()
{
  list< int > os ;
  os.push_back( 1 ) ;
  os.push_back( 2 ) ;
  os.push_back( 3 ) ;
  os.push_back( 4 ) ;
  os.push_back( 5 ) ;  

  // Forward iterators:  reference to .end() not invalidated when remove last elt.
  list<int>::iterator fwdEnd = os.end() ;
  printList( os ) ;
  os.erase( --os.end() ) ; // remove the 5 (last elt)
  printList( os ) ;
  if( fwdEnd == os.end() )  puts( "YES, fwdEnd==os.end() still, iterators not invalidated" ) ;  // I get __this__ result
  else puts( "NO: fwdEnd INVALIDATED" ) ;



  list<int>::reverse_iterator revEnd = os.rend() ;
  // remove the front element
  printList( os ) ;
  os.erase( os.begin() ) ; // removes the 1
  printList( os ) ;
  if( revEnd == os.rend() )  puts( "YES revEnd is still valid" ) ;
  else  puts( "NO: revEnd NOT valid" ) ; // I get __this__ result
}
```

Comment: The way I understand it, a reverse iterator doesn't point to what it seemingly points to. A "one past the beginning" reverse iterator wraps a normal interator that refers to the beginning. When the wrapped iterator is invalidated, so is the reverse iterator. But I don't have a citation from the standard to back this up.

Comment: I guess the other question would be: *"is `rbegin` similarly invalidated in the first example?"*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is due to the fact that a reverse iterator has a slightly different referencing logic than a regular iterator: it points to an element, but when dereferenced, it yields a reference to the previous element.

You will easily see this if you try the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    auto i = find(begin(v), end(v), 3);
    cout << *i << endl;

    vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator ri(i);
    cout << *ri << endl;
}
```

The output should be:

```
3
2
```

When a reverse iterator *physically* points to a certain element, it *logically* points to the element which precedes it. Thus, a reverse iterator physically pointing to the element in a collection with index `i`, when dereferenced, yields (a reference to) the element with index `i-1`:

```
                       i, *i
                       |
    -      1     2     3     4     5     6     -
                 |     | 
                 *ri   ri
```

This is the reason why an iterator return by `rend()` actually points to the first element in a collection, and not to the one before the first element. Removing the first element, therefore, invalidates it.

```
           begin, *begin                       end, *end
           |                                   |
    -      1     2     3     4     5     6     -
    |      |                             |     |
*rend      rend                    *rbegin     rbegin
```

This does not apply only to lists, but to all collections which offer bidirectional iterators.

Comment: So _there is no actual element_ called "1 in front of the beginning" .. whereas a forward iterator actually points to "1 past the end", a reverse iterator just points to the beginning, and when dereferenced, points to "1 in front of the beginning"

Comment: @bobobobo: I guess one could say so, although technically there is not even an "element called 1 past the end": there is just a *position* that an iterator return by `end()` points to, and that's the position past the position of the last element. But I guess that's what you meant to say after all, and in that case you are right, there is no "position before the beginning of a collection" that an iterator returned by `rend()` physically points to.