# Unable to get second field of map using end()

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

I am creating a map just for learning purpose to store some key value pairs. If I print the second field of map using `begin()` function I am able to print the second field of map but when I try to do same with last element of map using `end()` it is not able to print the second field. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

map<int,std::string> arr;

map<int,std::string>::iterator p;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    arr[1] = "Hello";   
    arr[2] = "Hi";   
    arr[3] = "how";   
    arr[4] = "are";
    arr[5] = "you"; 

    p = arr.begin();
    printf("%s\n",p->second.c_str()); 

    p =  arr.end();
    printf("%s\n",p->second.c_str());

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: for STL Containers, ".end()" yields an iterator to the "1-past-the-end-element" 
see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252002/what-is-the-past-the-end-iterator-in-stl-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the last element, use [reverse iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/rbegin):

```
map< int,std::string>::reverse_iterator p;
p = arr.rbegin();
if( p != arr.rend() ) {
  // Do whatever with, it points to the last element
} else {
  // map is empty
}
```

`std::map::end` will return the iterator to one past last element and dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

From [`std::map::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end) at en.cppreference

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the
>   container. This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it
>   results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

Dereferencing `end()` is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `end()` returns an iterator to 1 past the end of the map.  If you want the last element then you can use

```
p = --arr.end();
```

You cannot use

```
p = arr.rbegin()
```

As you cannot assign a reverse iterator to a forward iterator([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab4b4b2ac74d01b6)).  If you want to use `rbegin()` then you have to create a reverse iterator.

```
map<int,std::string>::reverse_iterator rit;
rit = arr.rbegin();

// or

auto rit = arr.rebegin();  //C++11 or higher required for this
```

Or you can convert it to a forward iterator using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4408182/4342498) by [visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219972/visitor)

As always you should check to make sure that you have a valid iterator.  If the container is empty `begin() == end()` and dereferencing either is undefined behavior.

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end

Comment: "`begin() == end()`" - I think `arr.empty()` is clearer. It also may be faster.

Comment: @NO_NAME I was just demonstrating that using `begin()` is the same as `end()` if the container is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--arr.end()` or `arr.rbegin()`.

`arr.end()` returns iterator to the element after the last element. This allows easier writing loops. This element is only for comparing. Dereferencing it is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

**std::SOMETHING.end()** doesn't return the last element, it returns past-the-end element. Check the C++ [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/). In essence what you are doing is trying to deference undefined memory location.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in other posts `end()` is an iterator one position past the last element in the map. Thus you should not try to get its fields. To get the last element you can use `rbegin()`.